# how to run yii form validation before my js file

Tags: javascript, jquery, yii2

I added some js and css files using assets to my app.
My problem is that I want to run some function when the user click the submit button, but only after yii validator checked if theres no errors.
Right now my function running before yii validator.

How can I do that?

Comment: Can you show us some code?

Comment: some one else answer. thanks anyway!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `afterValidateAttribute`. Try following:

```
$position = View::POS_END;
$validatejs = <<< JS
        $('#formID').on('afterValidateAttribute', function(event, attribute, messages) {
            if(messages.length == 0){
                 // No errors ... 
            }
        });
        JS;
        $this->registerJs($validatejs, $position);
```

Updated:

```
$('#formID').on('beforeValidate', function (event, messages, deferreds) {
    // called when the validation is triggered by submitting the form
    // return false if you want to cancel the validation for the whole form
}).on('beforeValidateAttribute', function (event, attribute, messages, deferreds) {
    // before validating an attribute
    // return false if you want to cancel the validation for the attribute
}).on('afterValidateAttribute', function (event, attribute, messages) {
    // ...
}).on('afterValidate', function (event, messages) {
    // ...
}).on('beforeSubmit', function () {
    // after all validations have passed
    // you can do ajax form submission here
    // return false if you want to stop form submission
});
```

Comment: hi thanks but what i try to do is loading wheel and if i do what you posted its start right after i start to fill the form. why is that?

Comment: Answer updated. You can use any of the above method which suits you. I think you should try afterValidate or beforeSubmit event :)

Answer (score 1):

The `beforeSubmit` event is triggered after all validation and right before the submit:

```
$('#formid').on('beforeSubmit', function(e) {
   // Do your things
   if (cannotSubmitBecauseOfProblem)
      e.result = false; // Prevent form submission.
}
```